# C passing pointer to pointer of char

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have a function that gets a char** str_array as such:

```
char** str_array = Init();
```

Init allocates an array of char*, which insist contains an array of char.

Then later on I want to free the memory, but I wanted to have a cleanup function, as such:

```
void FreeStr(char*** arg) {
  char** str = *arg;
  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    printf("Str %d: %s\n", i, str[i]);
    free(str[i]);
  }
  free(str);
}
```

This prints garbage and crashes. The inside of the for loop does work when it is in the same function as where str_array is declared, but not when called as such:

```
FreeStr(&str_array);
```

I am confused why this is not working. I thought the extra layer of pointer would make sure I still point to the right memory. What am I misunderstanding please?

Comment: You probably don't want `free(str[i])`. But can you show the definition of `Init`?

Comment: There's no need to pass the pointer to the string array rather than the array itself.

Comment: `'\0'` is a very weird way of specifying `NULL`. Incidentally, the function does implicitly assume that the last element of `str` is a `NULL` pointer, is this true? @jayant the difference between `++i` and `i++` doesn't matter here because the result of the third `for`-expression is discarded.

Comment: regarding this line: `void FreeStr(char*** arg) {`  you might want to read this article about 'three star programmers'  follow this link: <https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6911254> then click on the link for a three star programmer.   BTW: being called a 'three star programmer' is not necessarily a compliment.

Comment: Please post the `init()` function and how the `FreeStr()` function is called.

Comment: My issue was actually checking for '\0' instead of NULL. It was a typo that I didn't see, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the extra layer of indirection.  Define your function as:

```
void FreeStr(char** arg)
```

And call it like this:

```
FreeStr(str_array);
```

Also, `str[i] != '\0'` is not a good way to test for a null pointer.  You should be doing `str[i] != NULL`.  So your function should look like:

```
void FreeStr(char** str) {
  for (int i = 0; str[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    printf("Str %d: %s\n", i, str[i]);
    free(str[i]);
  }
  free(str);
}
```

Comment: Indirection can help if the original poster wants FreeStr to also set str_array to NULL to get rid of the pointer to memory which has been released.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified if Init() returns a fixed length array or it returns a NULL-terminated array. If the latter is the case, which is the usual practice, the correct code would be:

```
void FreeStr(char*** arg) {
  char** str = *arg;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; str[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    printf("Str %d: %s\n", i, str[i]);
    free(str[i]);
  }
  free(str);
  *arg = NULL;
}
```

this way, after calling

```
FreeStr(&str_array);
```

provided that str_array is actually a malloc()-allocated NULL-terminated array of malloc()-allocated strings, str_array becomes NULL (you don't want pointers to released memory hanging around, do you?) and all memory is freed.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I should be checking for NULL but was checking for '\0' for some reason, that was definitely a bad bug.

Comment: basically '\0' equals NULL on most architectures, so there was no bug, just a coding style issue